# Naming lists based on the names of text files

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, for-loop

I'm trying to write a function which takes word lists from text files and appends each word in the file to a list, with the same name as the text file. For instance, using the text files `Verbs.txt` and `Nouns.txt` would result in all the words in `Verbs.txt` being in a `verbs` list and all the nouns in a `nouns`list. I'm trying to do it in a `for` loop:

```
def loadAllWords():
    fileList = ['Adjectives.txt', 'Adverbs.txt', 'Conjunctions.txt',
                'IntransitiveVerbs.txt', 'Leadin.txt', 'Nounmarkers.txt',
                'Nouns.txt', 'TransitiveVerbs.txt']
    for file in fileList:
        infile = open(file, 'r')
        word_type = file[:-4]
        word_list = [line for line in infile]
    return word_list
```

Of course, I could do it easily once for each text file:

```
def loadAllWords():
    infile = open("Adjectives.txt", "r")
    wordList = []
    wordList = [word for word in infile]
    return wordList
```

but I'd like my function to do it automatically with each one. Is there a way to do this, or should I just stick with a for loop for each file?

Comment: Use the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) Luke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for that like (untested):

```
results = {}
for file in file_list:
    infile = open(file, 'r')
    word_type = file[:-4]
    results[word_type] = [line for line in infile]
return results
```

also you don't need the list comprehension, you can just do:

```
results[word_type] = list(infile)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create new variables with custom names by manipulating the `locals()` dictionary, which is where local variables are stored. But it is hard to imagine any case where this would be a good idea. I strongly recommend Stephen Roach’s suggestion of using a dictionary, which will let you keep track of the lists more neatly. But if you really want to create local variables for each file, you can use a slight variation on his code:

```
results = {}
for file in file_list:
    with open(file, 'r') as infile:
        word_type = file[:-4]
        results[word_type] = list(infile)
# store each list in a local variable with that name
locals.update(results)
```